# AJAX fetching undefined PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hey guys I am having a VERY difficult time with a specific problem in hand. I'm trying to create a database driven chat room that fetches posts with AJAX. However, when calling to fetch data with AJAX, I get an undefined index warning. I use the setinterval() function to call the javascript function that contains the AJAX. I get this warning when the timing of the setinverval() function is reached. How can I code this so when that variable is empty and the setinterval() function is reached, I stop getting the warning? Thanks in advance to all who will help. Btw this is my very first post so if additional information is needed please let me know. Thanks again!!

here is the chatRoom.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Chat - Customer Module</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery
/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
//If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});

//Load the file containing the chat log
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "log.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#chatbox").html(html);
                    //Insert chat log into the#chatboxdiv               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight")
   - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
$("#chatbox").animate({scrollTop:newscrollHeight},'normal');
   //Autoscroll to  bottom of div
            }               
        }
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 1500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds

//If user wants to end session
$("#exit").click(function(){
    var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
    if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}      
});
});
</script>

</head>
<?php
    include('functions.php'); 
    session_start();
?>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu">
    <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></b></p>
    <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Exit Chat</a></p>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>  
<div id="chatbox">
        <?php
            loadPosts();
        ?>
    </div>

<form name="message" action="">
    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php.post file

```
<?
include('functions.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
$text = $_POST['text'];

    $uName = $_SESSION['user'];
    $time = date("h:i A");

    postComment($time, $uName, $text);
}       
?>
```

The functions.php file

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
function loadPosts(){

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0){
        echo "No Posts Were Found";
    }

    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo "(" . $post['time'] . ") <b>" . $post['user'] . "</b>: " . $post['text']
. "<br />";
    }

}

function postComment($time, $userN, $userMessage){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat 
Values(null, '$time', '$userN', '$userMessage')") or die(mysql_error());
}

function exitChat(){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Finally the new file log.php

```
<?php
include('functions.php');
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
    loadPosts();    
?>
```

Comment: We can't fix code we can't see. Stop accessing an index that isn't present in the array and you'll stop getting notices about doing that.

Comment: I'm very sorry Dan Grossman. This is my first time posting and wasn't able to get the editing portion to work... :( I'll be posting it now! Thanks. I apologize again!

Comment: Please note that the mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used any more. Also your code is open to sql injection. If you switch to PDO and use that properly you'll also prevent sql injection.

Comment: hey Arjan thanks for the comment, I am aware of the sql injection. My main focus @ the moment is getting the code to work. I appreciate the tip on PDO, I'll definitely take a look!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys I figured it out!! Wow that took me almost a month to figure out!! Apparently, I was forced to separate the postComment() and loadPosts() functions into their own files. I left the postComment() inside the post.php page but placed the loadPosts() in another page. I am not really sure why this works but it does. It's not giving me an index error or removing all the chat content. I'll post the code if anyone is interested in checking it out! Btw, I wanted to thank everyone that contributed to this post and tried helping. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this line is where you're getting the undefined index notice:

```
$userPost = $_POST['userPost'];
```

Since your polling code accesses this file with no post data, so `$_POST` has no `userPost` index.

Delete that line and Do this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['userPost']))
  postComment($time, $userN, $_POST['userPost']);
```

Comment: hey Dan I tried what you suggested and the undefined warning stopped, however every time the setinterval() function is called(in my case every 8 seconds) it clears the chatbox. I'm assuming because the $userPost variable is empty and when it try's to update the chatbox it clears the previous posts.

Comment: If userPost is empty, your code should do nothing but load the posts. There is no code that clears any posts, it doesn't happen magically.

Comment: That's what I don't understand. When I click the post button it clears the chatbox screen. In order to retrieve the previous posts, I have to manually refresh the page and even after the setInterval() function timer completes the chatbox again clears itself until I manually refresh the page. Do you think it's the $.post call on my .click function?